# UiDatePicker displays but not UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uidatepicker

If I drop a UIDatePicker onto a UIView in IB and run the app, the date picker displays.  If I  delete the date picker, drop a UIPickerView onto the same UIView and run the app, the UIPickerView doesn't display.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue might be that the UIPicker has nothing to pick from.
The UIpicker lets the user select an item from a list.
 You need to supply some options for the user to pick from such as a list of colors where as the datepicker lets the user pick a date and it doesnt need the dev to provide a list of things to pick from.